# T-SQL: Convert the value of datetime field from UTC to CET timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a DB that stores dates as datetime with UTC offset.
How do I convert these dates from UTC to say CET in a select statement?

And is there are some kind of syntax sugar that takes care of the whole daylight autumn/winter and springs/summer offset thing?

**EDIT:
I've found [this](http://tsqltoolbox.codeplex.com) library on CodePlex useful:**

> **DateTimeUtil**
>
> A set of UDFs and configuration data for extended datetime handling, e. g. it offers easy timezone conversion incl. support for daylight saving times using native T-SQL (no CLRs).

Comment: Try this - `SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), ColumnWithUTCDate) as CETCol from YourTable;`

Comment: Just for curiosity are you using .NET? If yes then it will be much easier for you to handle Offset/timezone there

Comment: #Kirshnraj Rana +1, that's clever. Unfortunately, sometimes I will need the time in different timezones. 

#ShekharPankaj - No, just queries from ssms.

Comment: Look at this link: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3173/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server--part-1/ 
It lists all the steps.

Comment: `DATETIME` doesn't contain time zone information. CET is always one hour ahead of UTC. If you are doing it for only display purpose, simply add 1 hour to the field.

Comment: #Zoff Dino, this is not true. The CET offset is GMT +2 during the summer and GMT +1 during the winter. DST is a tricky beast because it varies across country and even state borders. In addition to that, some countries have different rules for applying DST, while others don't apply it all.

Comment: @VelislavMarinov I see where you are getting at. However, timezones are always defined as a specific offset from GMT. So CET is always +1. CEST (summer time) is always +2. Determining the *prevailing* timezone on a particular day is a bitch.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.udfToLocalTime(t.CreatedDateTime, '1'), 113)
FROM yourtable t
```

In case of update:

```
UPDATE yourtable t 
SET t.CreatedDateTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.udfToLocalTime(t.CreatedDateTime, '1'), 113)
```

Use a UDF as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfToLocalTime
(
   @UtcDateTimeAS DATETIME
   ,@UtcOffset AS INT = -8 --PST
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @PstDateTimeAS DATETIME
            ,@Year  AS CHAR(4)
            ,@DstStart  AS DATETIME
            ,@DstEndAS DATETIME
            ,@Mar1  AS DATETIME
            ,@Nov1  AS DATETIME
            ,@MarTime   AS TIME
            ,@NovTime   AS TIME
            ,@Mar1Day   AS INT
            ,@Nov1Day   AS INT
            ,@MarDiff   AS INT
            ,@NovDiff   AS INT

    SELECT  @Year   = YEAR(@UtcDateTime)
            ,@MarTime   = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -@UtcOffset, '1900-01-01 02:00'))
            ,@NovTime   = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -@UtcOffset - 1, '1900-01-01 02:00'))
            ,@Mar1  = CONVERT(CHAR(16), @Year + '-03-01 ' + CONVERT(CHAR(5), @MarTime), 126)
            ,@Nov1  = CONVERT(CHAR(16), @Year + '-11-01 ' + CONVERT(CHAR(5), @NovTime), 126)
            ,@Mar1Day   = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Mar1)
            ,@Nov1Day   = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Nov1)

    --Get number of days between Mar 1 and DST start date
    IF @Mar1Day = 1 
    SET @MarDiff = 7
    ELSE 
    SET @MarDiff = 15 - @Mar1Day

    --Get number of days between Nov 1 and DST end date
    IF @Nov1Day = 1 
    SET @NovDiff = 0
    ELSE 
    SET @NovDiff = 8 - @Nov1Day

    --Get DST start and end dates
    SELECT @DstStart   = DATEADD(DAY, @MarDiff, @Mar1)
            ,@DstEnd= DATEADD(DAY, @NovDiff, @Nov1)

    --Change UTC offset if @UtcDateTime is in DST Range
    IF @UtcDateTime >= @DstStart AND @UtcDateTime < @DstEnd 
    SET @UtcOffset = @UtcOffset + 1

    --Get Conversion
    SET @PstDateTime = DATEADD(HOUR, @UtcOffset, @UtcDateTime)
    RETURN @PstDateTime
END
```

Comment: May be I'm missing something, but how do you account for the one hour for summer and winter time.

Comment: @VelislavMarinov . Have modified solution to take care  of daylight savings. Tested for SELECT convert(VARCHAR, dbo.udfToLocalTime('2014-02-15 00:00:00.000','1'), 113) 
SELECT convert(VARCHAR, dbo.udfToLocalTime('2014-04-15 00:00:00.000', '1'), 113) 
SELECT convert(VARCHAR, dbo.udfToLocalTime('2014-09-15 00:00:00.000','1'), 113) 
SELECT convert(VARCHAR, dbo.udfToLocalTime('2014-11-15 00:00:00.000', '1'), 113)

Comment: Assumption- Offset parameter is taken as the offset during winter

Answer (score 0):

It's perfect if your DB contains UTC dates. Better way is to use your OS timezone offset.

For example:

```
select
  dateadd(minute,DATEPART(TZ, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()), YourUTCDate) as timestamp
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to convert Date TImeZones.

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION timezoneConverter 
(v_date in date, inputDateZone in varchar2 default 'UTC', outputDateZone in varchar2 default 'UTC')
return date AS date_out date;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        to_date(
            to_char(FROM_TZ(to_timestamp(to_char( v_date,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ),'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
        to_char(inputDateZone)) AT TIME ZONE
        to_char(outputDateZone),
        'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    into date_out FROM dual;
    return date_out;
EXCEPTION
    when others then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Date:' || v_date || 'TZ:' || inputDateZone || '-' || outputDateZone || ' / ' || sqlcode || ' / ' || SQLERRM(sqlcode));
        --date_out := to_date(to_char(v_date-1/24, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'), 'yyyymmddhh24miss');
        date_out := null;
        return date_out;
END;
/
```

**DayLight** Central European Time ([`CET`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time)) vs Central European Summer Time ([`CEST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time))

[Short Hour](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?pl=1&lid=100,12,4575352&h=12&date=3/29/2020%7C3&hf=1) 2nd hour skipped. `Note: hours shift because clocks change forward 1 hour.`

```sql
--set serveroutput on; -- View -> Dbms Output : set serveroutput on [serveroutput must be set ON or OFF or OPTIMIZED or UNOPTIMIZED]
SELECT
 timezoneConverter(to_timestamp('2020-03-29T01:00Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'CET', 'UTC') CETtoUTC1, -- 29-MAR-2020 00:00:00
 timezoneConverter(to_timestamp('2020-03-29T02:00Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'CET', 'UTC') CETtoUTC2, -- (null)
 timezoneConverter(to_timestamp('2020-03-29T02:00Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'UTC', 'CET') UTCtoCET FROM dual; -- 29-MAR-2020 04:00:00

-- Date:29-MAR-2020 02:00:00TZ:CET-UTC / -1878 / ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval
```

[Long Hour](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?pl=1&lid=100,12,4575352&h=12&date=10/25/2020%7C3&hf=1) 2nd hour repeats `Note: hours shift because clocks change backward 1 hour.`

```sql
SELECT
 timezoneConverter(to_timestamp('2020-10-25T02:00Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'UTC', 'CET') UTCtoCET, -- 25-OCT-2020 03:00:00
 timezoneConverter(to_timestamp('2020-10-25T02:00Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'CET', 'UTC') CETtoUTC2, -- 25-OCT-2020 01:00:00
 timezoneConverter(to_timestamp('2020-10-25T01:00Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi"Z"'), 'CET', 'UTC') CETtoUTC1 FROM dual; -- 24-OCT-2020 23:00:00
```

---

The following example converts the datetime value of one time zone to another time zone: [`docs.oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions007.htm#SQLRF00401)

```sql
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('1999-12-01 11:00:00', 
      'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') 
   AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' "West Coast Time" 
   FROM DUAL;

West Coast Time
------------------------------------------------
01-DEC-99 08.00.00.000000 AM AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```